# phonegap android geolocation. Some Attributes are always null

Tags: android, geolocation, cordova

As an example I implemented a method wich shows me all the geolocation stuff.

```
    function showLocation() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);
}

        function onGeoSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '           + position.coords.latitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Longitude: '          + position.coords.longitude             + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude: '           + position.coords.altitude              + '<br />' +
                        'Accuracy: '           + position.coords.accuracy              + '<br />' +
                        'Altitude Accuracy: '  + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy      + '<br />' +
                        'Heading: '            + position.coords.heading               + '<br />' +
                        'Speed: '              + position.coords.speed                 + '<br />' +
                        'Timestamp: '          + new Date(position.timestamp)          + '<br />';
}
```

so I took a walk arround the block pressing this button:

```
<input type="submit" data-theme="d" name="login" id="login" value="Position" onclick="showLocation()"/>
```

However, the Attributes for Altitude, Heading and Speed always shows null. 
Altitude Accuracy also shows null, but the phonegap docu says it´s not working with android. So why is this not working?
thanks in advance, Daniel

Comment: http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#coordinates_interface it might be device specific, as to whether or not those parameters are supported "If the implementation cannot provide {those variables you're having trouble with} information, the value of this attribute must be null."

Comment: ah I was afraid it´s that, thank you. Ill accept your answer if you copy your comment in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html#coordinates_interface

it might be device specific, as to whether or not those parameters are supported "If the implementation cannot provide {those variables you're having trouble with} information, the value of this attribute must be null."

Answer (score 1):

From the tests I have done with phonegap 1.5, I have found that many of these attributes only return a value if my device is in motion. I do get an accuracy number at rest (I think I have a gps sensor in my phone), it goes from a few thousand meters down to less than 100. However, I only get a heading and speed when the device is moving. Also the heading is the direction of travel, it is independent of the orientation of the phone.